# How convert milliseconds to human readable format in org mode table?

Tags: org-mode

Windows 10, Emacs 26.1

In org file:

```
| _id |          Date |   expiresDate |   amount |
|-----+---------------+---------------+----------|
| 633 | 1539190765000 | 1573336800000 |   766.26 |
| 184 | 1542045137000 | 1576101600000 |    851.4 |
| 110 | 1542348620000 | 1576447200000 |   936.54 |
| 634 | 1539190765000 | 1573336800000 | 40788.33 |
| 185 | 1542045137000 | 1576101600000 | 41041.81 |
|   7 | 1543213783000 | 1577311200000 | 41295.29 |
| 756 | 1538629706000 | 1573768800000 |    177.0 |
```

In columns "**Date**" and "**expiresDate**" dates are in **milliseconds** (from January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT).
E.g. **1539190765000** = **10.10.2018 16:59**

I use this site for convert https://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm

So I need to convert both dates columns to human readable format: `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm`

So the result must be like this:

```
| _id | Date               | expiresDate        | amount |
|-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------|
| 633 | <2018-10-10 16:59> | <2019-11-19 22:00> | 766.26 |
...
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `calc` function `unixtime` in a table formula.
So, first add 2 additional columns to your table:

```
| _id |          Date | Date hrf               |   expiresDate | epires Date hrf        |   amount |
|-----+---------------+------------------------+---------------+------------------------+----------|
| 633 | 1539190765000 |                        | 1573336800000 |                        |   766.26 |
...
```

Then add following formula at the end of your table and evaluate it:

```
#+TBLFM: $3=unixtime($2/1000)::$5=unixtime($4/1000)
```

Now every line of those extra columns get filled with the converted dates. You could delete non needed columns afterwards.

`unixtime` calculates from seconds (since 1.Jan.1970) to human readable format. So, to be able to use `unixtime` you need to convert milliseconds to seconds.

---

*Edit, as reply to comments:*
Use following two table formulas (with my table structure from above) to get exactly the date string you wanted:

```
#+TBLFM: $3='(format-time-string "<%F %H:%M>" (seconds-to-time (/ $2 1000)) t);N
#+TBLFM: $5='(format-time-string "<%F %H:%M>" (seconds-to-time (/ $4 1000)) t);N
```

Put point (the cursor) at the formula line (which should be right below the table) and press `C-c C-c`.

Some explanation of the two table formulas above:

- the formula consists of `elisp` code (not `calc` functions)
- the `;N` tells org-mode to feed the elisp code with a number (instead of a string)
- milliseconds need to be converted to seconds, therefore the division by 1000

---

To just convert a single ms value, use following elisp function:

```
(defun my-ms2date-convert (ms)
  (interactive)
  (format-time-string "<%F %H:%M>" (seconds-to-time (/ ms 1000)) t))
```

Of course you could use this function for csv files, but you have to figure out yourself how to process every single value from a csv table.

Comment: suppose I has 1000 lines in table. How I can convert all of them to desire date format?

Comment: And is it possible to to convert dates not only in org mode? E.g. in CSV file?

Comment: @Alexei see edits, otherwise be more explicit with your questions.

Comment: I press C-c C-c but nothing happened. Only message in minibuffer "Local setup has been refreshed"

Comment: @Alexei put the formula right below the table, and the cursor at the formula before pressing 'C-c C-c'. Short introduction to tables and formulas is here: https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-spreadsheet-intro.html